# Cancel connection of blocking socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

I'm using the following code for client socket

```
int ConnectToServerSocket
    (
        char*   _serverIP,          //in
        char*   _serverPort,        //in
        SOCKET& _connectedSocket    //out
    )
{
    struct addrinfo *addrResult = NULL,hints;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof (hints));
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    int result = 0;
    if (getaddrinfo(_serverIP, _serverPort, &hints, &addrResult))
    {
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        return err;
    }

    _connectedSocket = socket(addrResult->ai_family, addrResult->ai_socktype, addrResult->ai_protocol);
    if (_connectedSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        freeaddrinfo(addrResult);
        return err;
    }

    if (connect(_connectedSocket, addrResult->ai_addr, (int)addrResult->ai_addrlen) != 0)
    {
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        closesocket(_connectedSocket);
        _connectedSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        return err;
    }
    return 0; //successful
}
```

The problem is I want to cancel the connection anytime, In the cancel event button, I called `closesocket(_connectedSocket);` but it was blocked by `connect()` function so long after return the error.

Someone can show me how to interrupt the `connect()` function immediately?

Many thanks,

T&T

Comment: Set socket to `O_NONBLOCK` using `fcntl`.

Comment: @alvits: Thank you! But if I use non-blocking socket, you can show me how to change the above code correctly?

Comment: The client does indeed block on connect() unless the socket is in non-blocking mode.

Comment: I suddenly realized you are using winsock2. My answer would work in Linux but I am not sure if it will work with winsock2. I'm deleting it to avoid giving incompatible answer.

Comment: You cannot release a resource in one thread when it is, or might be, being used by another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have another thread do the `connect`. That will allow you to wait for that other thread using whatever method, for however long, and with whatever abort mechanism you wish.

You don't need to abort the `connect` itself.

Comment: Thank you, maybe your way is simplest for my problem :)